# Nginx closes connection even with keep alive

Tags: nginx, go

So I have an issues which I'm not sure if it's a GO problem or issues with nginx configuration. Basically when trying to test a curl request to our servers, the connection unexpectedly gets closed, even though keep-alive is set to true. 
Below is the log I get back from nginx:

```
* About to connect() to sub.domain.com port 80 (#0)
* Trying W.X.Y.Z... connected
> POST /br HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: sub.domain.com
> Accept: */*
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Length: 1635
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2016 15:31:21 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.6.1
< Content-Length: 3158
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{"data1": "some data", "data2": "some data2" ....
* Connection #0 to host sub.domain.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
... "dataX": "some dataX", "dataY": "some dataY}
```

Our nginx keep-alive configuration:

```
keepalive_timeout 150;
keepalive_requests 5000;
```

The nginx is sitting in front of a Go server, although it shouldn't impact it. Any tips on how to go about trying to figure out why the keep-alive is closing the connection?

Edit: 
complete nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 60000;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    error_log   /dev/null;
    access_log   /dev/null;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout 150;
    keepalive_requests 5000;
    client_header_timeout 2;
    client_body_timeout 2;

    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 2;
    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream go_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 weight=1;
    keepalive 2000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 1.domain.com 2.domain.com 3.domain.com 4.domain.com 5.domain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://go_app;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

And the go-code responsible for writing the response:

```
func Success(response http.ResponseWriter, value string) {
    response.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    fmt.Fprint(response, value)
    response.Write(nil)
}
```

Comment: It's probably the backend that's closing the connection. What is the proxy config, and what is the Go server doing with the connection?

Comment: @JimB I have added more information included function that's responsible for writing the response in go and the complete nginx config.

Comment: Not sure what's going on from the info provided here. You may need to log what's happening between nginx and the backend. Also, are you certain that it's the server closing the connection? Have you tested with an http/1.1 client making multiple requests with same connection?

Comment: How long is it taking for the client to deliver the POST body? How long is it taking for the server (either your Go http handler or NGINX) to deliver the reply to the client. You've got some timeouts in your NGINX config that may be impacting the keepalive. I wonder if you're trying to keep a long lived connection for something like "streaming" data back to the client. If that's the case, then the send_timeout setting is suspect to me. A tcpdump between client and server should at least tell you which end is initiating the close.

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If yes, would help the community if you can post the answer.